# NoSuchMethodError thrown on Realm 3.1

Tags: android, realm

Since we updated to Realm 3.1, we get these crashes. I could not find a solution for this yet.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='notifyChangeListeners' signature='([Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Lio/realm/internal/OsObject;
>          at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeCommitTransaction(SharedRealm.java)
>          at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.commitTransaction(SharedRealm.java:251)
>          at io.realm.BaseRealm.commitTransaction(BaseRealm.java:320)
>          at io.realm.Realm.commitTransaction(Realm.java:127)
>          at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1348)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in Realm, there's already a fix for future release and a workaround for now 
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4463#issuecomment-293150605